# Syntax error in file: adodb-postgresql.inc.php

Tags: postgresql, adodb-php

*System: Slackware-14.1, httpd-2.4.16. php-5.6.24, php-pgsql-5.6.24, adodb-5.14.*

I am no longer interested in this approach and will develop my own application using different tools. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: I had a quick look at XRMS source code, which appears to bundle ADOdb V4.68, yet you mention using 5.14... ADOdb 4 was written for PHP 4, so I wouldn't be surprised if you're getting errors trying to use it with PHP 5.6. ADOdb 5.14 is also very out-of-date (current version is 5.20.5), and no longer supported.

Comment: I will upgrade adodb to 5.20.5 if you think that will allow the application to run. Any other suggestions you have are appreciated.

Comment: I can't guarantee it will make things right; in fact the upgrade may cause other issues, I just can't tell. Give it a try, see what happens - but backup first ;-)